# Built-in date time picker control in Android that looks like the datetime picker of the Calendar Application

Tags: android

Is the control shown in the image below built-in in the Android Framework or it is a custom control. If it is custom control, should it be built using a button with background that pops a calendar dialog on click?

[image: snapshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just normal TextViews with a custom background selector and an `OnClickListener` that triggers the dialog.

If you want to know how a certain view or layout is built, you can use a tool called `hierachyviewer` *(which I used here too)*. It shows the view hierachy of running apps on your device and is included in the Android SDK in your `ANDROID_SDK/tools` directory. The program is a bit unintuitive at first, but certainly a useful thing to know. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) for more information about this.